# SQL CASE clause in ORDER BY clause with JOIN

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have 3 table:

1. outfit
2. item
3. color

outfit table have realtion with items with manyToMany realtion
item table have relation with color with manyToOne relation

Relations look like this

[image: DB Scheme]

I need to create search functionality with this logic: 
if user enter "red airmax" I look for outfits
if there are not outfits with this name I search pruducts
if there also not outfits with this name I search by color

So when I search with color I got items with color red but not airmax,
and I want to search airmax too in items by this logic,
if DB find out products with color red, check also is product name airmax

I am using symfony/doctrine
So my sql code with colors will be like this

```sql
SELECT o FROM OutfitsBundle:Outfits o
LEFT JOIN o.item i
LEFT JOIN i.color c
WHERE c.name LIKE '%red%'
OR c.name LIKE '%airmax%'
GROUP BY o.id 
ORDER BY 
CASE 
 WHEN i.name LIKE '%airmax%' THEN 1
 ELSE 0
END
```

So this is wrong because if I need to sort by case clause I need to add i.id on GROUP BY clause,
but I need to get only outfits

The goal is to get first that products which have keyword in his name

For now I haven't any idea for searching in item name only airmax not red, if anyone know how t do it please say about it also

Example of DB

**Table: Outfits**
id: 1, name: 'vero moda';
id: 2, name: 'street one';

**Table: Items**
id: 1, color_id: 3, name: 'Vero moda sweatch';
id: 2, color_id: 1, name: 'Nike Airmax';
id: 3, color_id: 2, name: 'Pepe jeans';
id: 4, color_id: 2, name: 'Naketano';
id: 5, color_id: 3, name: 'Dockers By Gerli Stiefel';
id: 6, color_id: 2, name: 'Jeans';

**Table: Outfititems**
id: 1, outfit_id: 1, item_id: 1;
id: 2, outfit_id: 1, item_id: 5;
id: 3, outfit_id: 1, item_id: 6;
id: 4, outfit_id: 2, item_id: 2;
id: 5, outfit_id: 2, item_id: 3;
id: 6, outfit_id: 2, item_id: 4;

**Table: Color**
id: 1, name: black;
id: 2, name: blue;
id: 3, name: pink;

Comment: This is quite unclear. Would you please show a few records of sample data for all 3 tables and also the expected result?

Comment: That join there does not reflect the "many to many" relationships. Aren't you forgetting two relation tables?

Comment: You miss the `ON` condition on both `JOIN`

Comment: Oh sorry product-color is manytoone relation, I will edit

Answer (score 0):

You provide insufficient detail, but I'll try...

```
SELECT distinct o.name

FROM outfits o
  inner JOIN item i = i.itemid = o.itemid
  inner JOIN color c on c.colorid = i.colorid

WHERE c.name LIKE '%red%'
   OR c.name LIKE '%airmax%'
   or o.name like '%red%'
   OR o.name LIKE '%airmax%'
   or i.name like '%red%'
   OR i.name LIKE '%airmax%'

ORDER BY 
CASE 
   WHEN o.name LIKE '%airmax%' THEN 1
   ELSE 0
END desc
```

Comment: I chenged some lines, after that it worked, thank you